# Add redhat yum repo to oracle linux

Tags: yum, repository, oracle-linux

I'm running oracle linux 7.2.

The Oracle yum repo is comparatively small, containing only core enterprise packages.

How can I add the redhat yum repo so I can install other userspace utilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably consider the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repositories instead. Red Hat's official repository is also quite lean, and mixing Oracle and Red Hat base packages is a Very Bad Idea(TM). (EPEL is quite careful not to trample on core packages).

If you don't *need* Oracle support, maybe you should switch to [CentOS](https://www.centos.org), which is more or less RHEL rebuilt (+ EPEL, as needed), to get a somewhat wider selection of software.

Comment: Hmm. EPEL also seems extremely sparse. No ffmpeg or imagemagick for instance

Comment: @retrodev, sure. Red Hat (and EPEL, a project under the same umbrela) is militantly open source only. ffmpeg is *not* open source. Missing ImageMagick is certainly strange, it is part of Fedora. You'd have to ask the EPEL folks.

Answer (score 2):

For packages not available in the OEL repositories add the EPEL repository and the [RepoForge, formerly RPMForge repository](http://repoforge.org/use/). You can find imagemagick in [Remi's Repository](http://blog.remirepo.net/pages/Config-en). Also consider using another distribution like Ubuntu if you need access to a lot of userspace tools. You can run a Ubuntu VM inside VirtualBox which is in the OEL public yum repository.